# How to call a method defined in angular service

Tags: angular, service, angular-services

I am just learning angular day by day. I am currently learning angular services and I am really confuse about some thing that is confusing me and I am unable to understand it.

Here is the code.

Service Code

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';


@Injectable()
export class DataService {

    private goals = new BehaviorSubject<any>(['The initial goal','Another silly life goal']);
    goal = this.goals.asObservable();

    constructor() { }

    changeGoal(goal_param) {
        this.goals.next(goal_param)
    }

}
```

Home component code

```
ngOnInit() {
        this.itemscount = this.goals.length;
        this._data.goal.subscribe(res => this.goals = res);
        this._data.changeGoal(this.goals);
    }
```

Home component template code

```
<div class="container color-dark">
  <div class="col">
    <p>Add a bucket list item</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <p>Your bucket list ({{itemscount}})</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container color-light">
  <div class="col">
    <p class="sm">Use this form below to add a new bucket list goal. What do you want to accomplish in your life?</p>

    <form>
      <input type="text" class="txt" name="item" placeholder="{{goalText}}" [(ngModel)]="goalText">
      <br><span>{{ goalText }}</span><br>
      <input type="submit" class="btn" [value]="btnText" (click)="additem()">
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <p class="life-container" *ngFor = "let goal of goals; let i = index" >
      <input type="text"  value=" {{ goal }}"  #goalInput disabled>
      <span class="edit_btn" (click)="edititem(i)" #goalbtn>Edit</span>
      <span class="delete_btn" (click)="removeitem(i)">Delete</span>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now the main point is this line which is confusing me
What this "goal" property is doing? we are not using this property in anywhere in service file but if i remove this "goal" property angular gives me error so I am confuse whats its use??

```
goal = this.goals.asObservable();
```

The second thing is I am passing goal_param from home component and receiving it inside service file but still the same question if I remove "goal" property this function don't work. What this function has to do with "goal" property?

```
changeGoal(goal_param) {
        this.goals.next(goal_param)
    }
```

I know It is a basic question but If someone will help me to understand this then I will be more motivated towards my learning.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You haven't shown your template (html) code for the component.  HTML templates can access public component variables (like `goal`).  Can you add that file as well?

Comment: @Pace kindly check it. I have added the html template.

Answer (score 0):

That service is enforcing encapsulation using the `goal` property.  You can think of it as similar to a class that has a getter method but no setter method.  Inside the service is a private `goals` subject.  A subject is both an `Observer` which allows you to "write" data and an `Observable` which allows you to "read" data.

The component needs to be able to subscribe to `goals` so that it gets the updates whenever the goals change.  One way to do this would be to make `goals` public but that would violate encapsulation because then anyone would be able to modify it.

Instead the `goal` variable is created.  `asObservable` returns a read-only view of a subject.  So `goal` is really just a read only view of `goals`.  The `goal` variable is used in the component right here:

```
this._data.goal.subscribe(res => this.goals = res);
```

The component is subscribing to the data service's goals.  Whenever the data services goals change the component puts a copy of the latest value in its own `goals` property.  The component's `goals` property is then read by the template to display the page.

The reason for this encapsulation is that it forces all modification to the `goals` variable to happen via the `DataService`.  This allows you to control how `goals` is modified.  For example, maybe `goals` can only be modified by certain kinds of users, when the system is in a certain state, or some other criteria.  Maybe, whenever `goals` is modified you want to massage the data into a certain format or do some kind of computation on it.